# TensorFlow LlinearRegressor example failed to create a directory in path C:\Users and raise a exception

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning machine-learning.At the same time,I use TensorFlow.

**Python**:3.5.2

**System**:Windows 10

**TensorFlow**:1.0.1，installed by pip

---

But I have some problems when I run the following code.The code is [TensorFlow Basic usage](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started#basic_usage).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=1)]
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)
x = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x}, y, batch_size=4, 
  num_epochs=1000)
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)
print(estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn))
```

---

This is the result:

```
    WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_dq8vxf6
    E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits
    E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "CountExtremelyRandomStats" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: CountExtremelyRandomStats
    E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "FinishedNodes" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: FinishedNodes
    E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "GrowTree" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GrowTree
    E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ReinterpretStringToFloat" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ReinterpretStringToFloat
    E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "SampleInputs" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SampleInputs
    E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ScatterAddNdim" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScatterAddNdim
    E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNInsert" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNInsert
    E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNRemove" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNRemove
    E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TreePredictions" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TreePredictions
    E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "UpdateFertileSlots" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UpdateFertileSlots
    WARNING:tensorflow:Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank (2) for column. Will attempt to expand dims. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.
    WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\head.py:1362: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
    Instructions for updating:
    Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\Desktop\Python\ML\ML\LinerRegressor.py", line 10, in <module>
        estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 280, in new_func
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py", line 426, in fit
        loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py", line 981, in _train_model
        config=self.config.tf_config) as mon_sess:
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 315, in MonitoredTrainingSession
        return MonitoredSession(session_creator=session_creator, hooks=all_hooks)
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 601, in __init__
        session_creator, hooks, should_recover=True)
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 428, in __init__
        h.begin()
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 324, in begin
        self._summary_writer = SummaryWriterCache.get(self._checkpoint_dir)
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\summary\writer\writer_cache.py", line 58, in get
        logdir, graph=ops.get_default_graph())
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\summary\writer\writer.py", line 289, in __init__
        event_writer = EventFileWriter(logdir, max_queue, flush_secs)
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\summary\writer\event_file_writer.py", line 63, in __init__
        gfile.MakeDirs(self._logdir)
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 301, in recursive_create_dir
        pywrap_tensorflow.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.as_bytes(dirname), status)
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
        next(self.gen)
      File "C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 467, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
        pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Failed to create a directory: C:\Users/赵子龙
```

---

Now I can remove the first warning

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_dq8vxf6
```

by modifying the code
 `estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)`
to 
`estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features,model_dir='/tmp')`.

---

After the change,my code can run well and no exception and no the first warning.
Here is the result:

```
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "CountExtremelyRandomStats" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: CountExtremelyRandomStats
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "FinishedNodes" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: FinishedNodes
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "GrowTree" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GrowTree
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ReinterpretStringToFloat" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ReinterpretStringToFloat
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "SampleInputs" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SampleInputs
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ScatterAddNdim" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScatterAddNdim
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNInsert" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNInsert
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNRemove" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNRemove
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TreePredictions" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TreePredictions
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "UpdateFertileSlots" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UpdateFertileSlots
WARNING:tensorflow:Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank (2) for column. Will attempt to expand dims. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\head.py:1362: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.
WARNING:tensorflow:Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank (2) for column. Will attempt to expand dims. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\赵子龙\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\head.py:1362: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.
WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping summary for global_step, must be a float or np.float32.
{'global_step': 1000, 'loss': 5.6782592e-09}
```

But I got another error:*the result **{'global_step': 1000, 'loss': 5.6782592e-09}** is different from the official answer **{'global_step': 1000, 'loss': 1.9650059e-11}**.*

**Another Question:**

---

When I change `model_dir='/tmp'` to `model_dir='/Users/tmp'`,I will get the same
error as I didn't add the parameter.
P.S:Users is a directory in C disk.
I want to know whether Users is a different directory so python failed to create a directory in Users in Win10.

**Quession Summary**

---

1. Why the program will raise an exception if I don't add `model_dir` parameter?
2. Why I get a wrong result?
3. Why the program fail to create a directory in `C:\Users`

I hope someone can help me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Why the program will raise an exception if I don't add model_dir parameter?

It is not an exception, it's a **WARNING**. Normally I would create a sub folder inside the working directory to keep outputs (For TensorBoard).

> 2. Why I get a wrong result?

Compare to the result from official ('loss': 1.9650059e-11), your answer ('loss': 5.6782592e-09) is relatively close.

Different result does not mean *wrong result*. In machine learning we try to minimize the cost function, and 5.6782592e-09 is a relatively good result. Also if you try to run the same code multiple times, you can see it shows different results.

> 3. Why the program fail to create a directory in C:\Users

You've probably got a **PermissionDeniedError**, like explained in 1. I would suggest use a relative path instead: `model_dir='./output'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Where would the model file be saved if you use relative path?? I could not find the saved model file;p

Comment: It should be inside the current working directory `pwd`.